# Operator ">" doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript

The `>` operator does not work correctly for me!

```
var message = document.getElementById("success");
message.innerHTML = startNumber + ">" + endNumber;
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = startNumber > endNumber;
```

> input1: startNumber=45 , endNumber=1
> ////// output1 : 45>1 true
>
> input2: startNumber=45 , endNumber=5
> //////// output2:45>5 false

---

Updated (my variable declaration before/after) Thanks:)

```
<!--Before-->
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="start_field" placeholder="start of">
            <input type="text" id="end_field" placeholder="end at">
            <input type="button" id="startbtn" value="Start">
        </form>

var startPage =document.getElementById("start_field").value;
var endPage = document.getElementById("end_field").value;

<!--After-->
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="start_field" placeholder="start of">
            <input type="text" id="end_field" placeholder="end at">
            <input type="button" id="startbtn" value="Start">
        </form>

var startPage =new Number(document.getElementById("start_field").value);
var endPage = new Number(document.getElementById("end_field").value);
```

Comment: Are your inputs strings or numbers?  What are `typeof startNumber` and `typeof endNumber`?

Comment: Show us how you declare your variables, give more context.

Comment: In practice, an apparent discovery that a fundamental language feature is severely broken rarely turns out to be genuine.

Comment: Here’s an illustrative example of the issue you’re probably facing: http://jsfiddle.net/ebpamdo9/9/

Comment: yes! the problem was my variable declaration. I define them as var!
thanks:). I'm new in javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're working with strings, not numbers.  The *string* "45" is not greater than the *string* "5".

You can force the strings to be interpreted numerically if you want:

```
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = +startNumber > +endNumber;
```

Comment: “You're working with strings, not numbers.” — Where are `startNumber` and `endNumber` treated as strings?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite they're not *treated* as strings; by inference however it's clear that in the code in the OP, they *are* strings. (Well, I guess they're treated as strings by the `>`, but again that's because `>` understands that strings should be compared lexicographically.)

Comment: that would explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = parseInt(startNumber) > parseInt(endNumber);
```

to force numerical comparison (a.o.t. string comparison)

Comment: Bear in mind that [it may be advisable to specify base-10 parsing when using `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) — i.e. `parseInt(startNumber, 10)`.

Comment: I consider **not** giving the radix a much desired feature, it allows for `0xff < 256`

Comment: Sure, but in some implementations it also allows `045 < 256`.